# javascript and css styling

Tags: javascript, css

Basically i just want to have **padding** to the left and not all around on this code:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #000";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.background="#FFF";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.padding-left="10px";    
}
```

But i don't know the syntax as padding-left breaks the argument. Is there a better way to do this without using a CSS as there are different styles depending on the if/else statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In native js you want paddingLeft not padding left

```
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.paddingLeft="10px";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: 
`document.getElementById("livesearch").style.paddingLeft="10px";`

Answer (score 1):

its always good to catch your variables on top as well,

```
var liveSearch = document.getElementById("livesearch")
liveSearch.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a reference that explains which javasceript term corresponds to which css. like this
[This page](http://www.ajaymatharu.com/css-properties-to-javascript-reference-conversion/)

But generally its a good practice to use css whenever possible. This separation between javascript and css is recommended.